# How to switch between the tags in Git

Tags: git

I am new to git. And I am facing problems while moving between the tags. I want to switch between the tags. Like if I have two versions. For example. 
version 1.0
version 2.0
so I want to move from version 2.0 to version 1.0 in Git.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In git, a tag is given a name, which in git terminology is its reference.  A tag in reality is more like an alias to a specific commit id (which is also a reference).

See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References

So to switch between tags you would use the same technique that you would use to switch between other references such as branches or commits... `git checkout <tagname>`.

Answer (score 11):

You are probably looking for:

```
git checkout tag
```

`git checkout` can be used to checkout any commit and after that it can be used with a branch name to go back to a named branch.